# Code or psuedo-code for linear bottleneck assignment (LBAP)?

Tags: variable-assignment, graph-theory, linear-programming

I'm building a robot simulator where I have n robots that need to go to n separate locations. All the robots start moving concurrently.  When a robot gets to its assigned location it stops moving.  The total amount of time needed for all robots to reach their locations is determined by the longest length that a given robot needs to reach its assigned location.  I'd like to minimize this longest length by clever assignment of destinations to robots.

Apparently this problem is the ["Linear bottleneck assignment problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bottleneck_assignment_problem).

I couldn't find any code to solve this problem.  Anyone have any pseudo-code, or actual code (any language fine, Ruby/Java preferred) to solve this efficiently?

Comment: I reworded the question to make it clearer.  I don't believe the question is overly broad -- I'm asking for code to solve the LBAP problem.  One person has posted where to find this code, and another has posted a possible solution (I'm not sure if it solves LBAP).  Why is this question too broad?

Answer (score 2):

The threshold algorithm is one of the standard algorithms for solving the linear bottleneck assignment problem.  A quick search didn't turn up pseudocode that I could easily copy and paste here, but pseudocode is given on page 175 of *Assignment Problems*, by Rainer Burkard, Mauro Dell'Amico, and Silvano Martello.  Here's the Google books link to the [relevant page](http://books.google.com/books?id=nHIzbApLOr0C&pg=PA175&dq=%22threshold%20algorithm%20for%20the%20lbap%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8Di0UPXUBOquiALZ04GQBg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22threshold%20algorithm%20for%20the%20lbap%22&f=false).  A few pages later they give another algorithm that exploits duality, but I'm not as familiar with that one.

Answer (score 0):

The LBAP (linear bottleneck assignment) is only one specific sub-class in a whole family of **assignment and path-routing problems** that are pertinent to your case.

You have quite a choice when deciding on the **MinMax** routing algorithm to implement for your n robots.
Here's what I'd do: I'd start with the simplest implementation of **Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm.**

The [wikipedia page for Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) has a nice visual example, but their pseudo code looks more daunting than it needs to be. It even links to [robot motion planning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_planning) though from your question it looks like you are looking for path-algorithms to implement.

**[updated based on OP's clarification re. MinMax]**

Dijkstra still works, but you need to a few additional steps.
Here's the basic strategy:

```
For each robot r = 1 to n
   calculate the shortest time-path for r from source of r to sink of r - (suggest starting with Dijkstra's) [if you are assuming constant speeds, then distance and length become equivalent]
Next r
```

**MinMax schema:**

1. sort all the paths (times) by time taken and take the longest one. (This is your theoretical minmax time.) - let's call it `t_max`
2. Ever other robot r has a time `"slack"`- `t_max`  minus  `time_r`
3. Take each pair of robots and see if their paths conflicts.

   - If no conflict, you are done.
   - If yes to conflict, then you have to reroute (conflicted node/edge avoidance) but inside of the slack time. (Simplest rerouting is to wait until the conflicting robot clears the edge or intersection.)
4. If you are able to route within `slack` , you are done. Otherwise, update t_max to be the longest (rerouted) path.

Here are some examples of Dijkstra code that you should be able to use. (Web search will yield tons more.)

1. http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/programs/graph/Dijkstra-java.html (Java)
2. [Here's a gist in Ruby](https://gist.github.com/1001947)

**Additional Notes:**

1. You don't have to limit yourself to Dijkstra's method. You can swap out and try other routing algorithms as you find them. Try out a few routing algorithms.
2. Remember to check for conflicts. ( i.e. Two robots being at the same node at the same time t) The most basic implementation of conflict-free routing involves some precedence rules for one robot to wait until the node is clear before it proceeds.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't understand how a shortest path algorithm like Dijkstra's can be used to minimize the maximum distance traveled by any robot.  Can you explain the connection between finding the shortest path and finding the optimal (minimizing the maximum path) assignment?

Comment: I didn't realize that you wanted the minmax distance for all robots. Dijkstra should still work, and I have updated the response to handle this additional requirement. Hope the basic re-routing schema (in the event of conflicts) makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, still not getting how this is equivalent to solving LBAP.  How "conflicts" are dealt with is outside the scope of the question about how to solve LBAP.  Also, what is sink-of-R?  I'm assuming we have n robots and n goals.  We're trying to figure out which goal each robot should go to.

Comment: It looks like we are not quite in synch. It might help if you can provide a small example (with 3 to 4 robots) of what you are trying to achieve. If there are 3 robots and 3 goals, then you'd generate shortest-paths for the 3^2 combinations, use the distance as the objective function and solve an assignment problem to minimize time taken.

Comment: The path and path length from robot Rx to Goal Gy is known.  It is the geometric distance between them (a straight line segment).  No planning is needed.  The only question is which robot should go to which goal to minimize the maximum distance traveled.  Not sure what example is needed -- I'm looking for code that efficiently solves LBAP.